# Data value "0" has invalid format error in redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We are facing a weird problem with one of our query. 
Below is the query we are running

```
INSERT into test 
SELECT 
    member.name as mem_name, 
    CASE WHEN ( member.dob>0 AND length (member.dob)=8 ) THEN (DATEDIFF(year,to_date("dob",'YYYYMMDD'), to_date(20140716,'YYYYMMDD'))) WHEN ( member.dob=0 ) Then 0 END As Age, 
    20140716021501 
FROM 
    member
```

Below is the sample data present in our table.

```
|name           |dob
|Ajitsh         |0        |
|rk             |51015    |
|s_thiagarajan  |19500130 |
|madhav_7       |19700725 |
|1922           |0        |
|rekha          |25478    |
|vmkurup        |0        |
|ravikris       |19620109 |
|ksairaman      |0        |
|sruthi         |0        |
|rrbha          |19630825 |
|sunilsw        |0        |
|sunilh         |0        |
|venky_pmv      |19701207 |
|malagi         |0        |
|an752001       |0        |
|edsdf          |19790201 |
|anuanand       |19730724 |
|fresh          |19720821 |
|ampharcopharma |19590127 |
|Nanze          |19621123 |
```

The date of birth is stored in bigint as `YYYYMMDD` format.
In the data there are some rows, in which date is invalid like 0, 51015.
On some instances this query raises the following error.

```
INSERT INTO test not successful
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
INSERT into test 
SELECT 
    member.name as mem_name, 
    CASE WHEN ( member.dob>0 AND length (member.dob)=8 ) THEN (DATEDIFF(y...

ERROR: Data value "0" has invalid format
    Detail: 
    -----------------------------------------------
    error:  Data value "0" has invalid format
    code:      1009
    context:   PG ERROR
    query:     92776
    location:  pg_utils.cpp:2731
    process:   query1_30 [pid=1434]
    -----------------------------------------------


Execution time: 3.99s

1 statement failed.
```

But the strange thing is, it raises the error randomly and not all the time.
Many times it works without any change in query or dataset.
Sometime it also works in second or third attempt.
My doubt is that to_date function is giving this error. But why randomly 
and not gives error on every run.

To support my assumption I also tried this small query.
`SELECT to_date(20140716,'YYYYMMDD'), to_date(0,'YYYYMMDD');`
But this also creates the same scenario. It raises error randomly, while
runs smoothly rest of the times.

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this question? I've got a related issue. I'm performing a `WHERE (getdate()::date - date_value::date) <=90` operation, and the error returned is "Data value .... has invalid format".

The strange thing is that `getdate()::date - date_value::date` works as expected, but when used in the WHERE, it throws the error.

Comment: @Moon_Watcher, I didn't got satisfactory answer to this question. The one workaround I think you can do it use `WITH` clause. e.g. `WITH temp AS ( SELECT  getdate()::date - date_value::date as diff FROM tablename) SELECT columns FROM temp WHERE diff <=90`.

Answer (score 1):

If is it fine to ignore this type of values and just convert this to Date format you can follow the below way.

```
SELECT to_date('20140716','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('0','FMYYYYMMDD');
```

Here FM suppresses leading zeroes and trailing blanks that would otherwise be added to make the output of a pattern be fixed-width.

Comment: @llesh Thanks for the `FM` option. But my main concern is why do the error raises randomly and not every time the query is fired.